# System Cannot Find FIle Specified Document document = documentBuilder()

Tags: java, xml

In this

```
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(filename);
```

I am trying to read a group of Xml files through `buffered input stream`. When I enter file through in command prompt, I am getting an error `As System Cannot find the specified File` . Can someone please suggest how to continue from here

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String s = bufferRead.readLine();
            File dir = new File(s);
            String[] children = dir.list();
            if (children == null) {
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    String filename = children[i];
                    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(filename);
                    System.out.println(filename);
                    NodeList employees = document
                            .getElementsByTagName("connection");
                    for (int q = 0; q < employees.getLength(); q++) {
                        System.out.println(employees.getLength());
                        Node employee = employees.item(q);
                        NamedNodeMap attribute = employee.getAttributes();
                        Node nodeAttr = attribute.getNamedItem("server");
                        nodeAttr.setTextContent("aventador.am.lilly.com:1530");
                        Node nodeAttr1 = attribute.getNamedItem("service");
                        Node nodeAttr2 = attribute.getNamedItem("port");
                        nodeAttr1.setTextContent("tst806");
                        nodeAttr2.setTextContent("");

                    }
                    System.out.println(filename);
                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                            .newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory
                            .newTransformer();
                    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
                    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(
                            filename));
                    transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
                    System.out.println("The XML File was ");
                }
            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception sae1) {
            sae1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value that you pass from the command line? Which OS are you on? Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: folder name' i am using windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your else block, you're trying to do `Document document = documentBuilder.parse(filename);`

The filename argument should be an URI - meaning, the complete file path. But you are only passing the filename, so irrespective of your input directory, the DocumentBuilder is looking at the current directory for XML files. Change the below line

`String filename = children[i];`

to

`String filename = dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + children[i];`

This should fix the issue.